# How do I expose a WCF web service call response header in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I am using Visual Studio 2008 and have added a web reference that points to a WCF web service.
Visual Studio has generated a client class automatically, so all I need to do to call the web service is to create an instance of the client and call the method on it.

```
FoodPreferenceServiceClient client = new FoodPreferenceServiceClient(); 
FoodPreferenceServiceResponse = client.GetFoodPreference();
```

The *FoodPreferenceServiceClient* is the web service client that is automatically generated by VS.
The *GetFoodPreference* is the method on the web service that I am calling.

My problem is that I want to expose the actual HTTP header received in the above call,
such as client.GetHttpResponse() or something.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but you might want [OperationContext.IncomingMessageHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.incomingmessageheaders.aspx) instead for custom properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should be possible. Try:

```
using (var scope = new OperationContextScope())
{
    var client = new FoodPreferenceServiceClient(); 
    response = client.GetFoodPreference();

    var httpProperties = (HttpResponseMessageProperty)OperationContext.Current
                             .IncomingMessageProperties[HttpResponseMessageProperty.Name];

    var headers = httpProperties.Headers;
    // Now you should be able to work with WebHeaderCollection and find the header you need
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had to change your example slightly. You have OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders when it should be .IncomingMessageProperties. You might want to correct it in your answer - I don't have edit privileges

Comment: @Chris: Yes thanks, I was thinking about HTTP headers and wrote headers but I meant properties :) Headers are for incoming SOAP headers.

Comment: Do you know if the actual SOAP XML can be accessed in a similar way? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can't get the message headers through OeprationContext directly in client side, but you can develop a custom IClientMessageInspector, and in the interface you can get he SOAP XML message.

Comment: Thanks, I have already implemented that now. For anyone who is interested, this SO answer was very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493639