# How to get raw data from Web Service Request?

Tags: web-services, post, asmx

I want to check raw data string (raw xml) received by my web service methods (for logging and debugging purposes).

I saw recommendations: to handle 'BeginRequest' event in HttpApplication. But I don't see which field of 'Request' object contains this POST data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Related question: [Getting RAW Soap Data from a Web Reference Client running in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net)*

#### - Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net/428223#428223) answer using tracing? or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net/300821#300821) using a SoapExtension

> I made following changes in web.cofig
>   to get SOAP(Request/Response)
>   Envelope. It makes trace.log file
>   where all the required information are
>   present
>
> ```
> <system.diagnostics>
> <trace autoflush="true"/>
> <sources>
>   <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
>     <listeners>
>       <add name="TraceFile"/>
>     </listeners>
>   </source>
>   <source name="System.Net.Sockets" maxdatasize="1024">
>     <listeners>
>       <add name="TraceFile"/>
>     </listeners>
>   </source>
> </sources>
> <sharedListeners>
>   <add name="TraceFile" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="trace.log"/>
> </sharedListeners>
> <switches>
>   <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose"/>
>   <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose"/>
> </switches>
> ```

Comment: What is not set to verbose? : O

Comment: Ohh gosh... you saw an asnwer with broken xml, didn't you? :P I made a bad quote the first time, but you can seek the link to see the full posts :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find listed topics, thank you for help. Unfortunately, suggested approach didn't log anything... don't know why... Have found article on MSDN, will try to figure out...

Comment: Probably, I do need to do Trace.Write... ? But how can I access the row data in this case?

Comment: In debug mode, when VisualStudio is attached to project - I saw a verbose debug information (everything what is required) in 'Debug Output' window... but this data is not saved into specified log-file... don't know why.... If you have any ideas, please let me know! Thank you in advance

Comment: Issue was in access permissions to the log folder. Thank for the help

Answer (score 1):

It would not make sense to keep all the request post data in the request object since it could contain uploaded file and be very big.

I have two solutions for you:

1) Use **Fiddler** on the server and browse locally the website (using server name and not localhost since Fiddler cannot show localhost request/responses)

2) Use `System.Net` tracing: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947285

You can also use WireShark to look at the packets but this will not keep the request response context.

Comment: System.Net tracing is just perfect!