# Forming an HTTP request for a SOAP web service

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I trying to acces this SOAP Web Service (http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc) and I also have its WSDL files available

```
http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?wsdl
http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?wsdl=wsdl0
http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?xsd=xsd0
http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?xsd=xsd1
http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?xsd=xsd2
http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?xsd=xsd3
```

But I'm never worked with soap and I'm not finding the WSDL files clear enough.
What I'm trying to do is query the service for the different operations available, for example the **ListaMinistros** operation that takes a parameter *actualizacion* that is a date in the format yyyymmdd.
I have tried every possible combination to contact the service but it responds with a **Endpoint not found** response.
If you could provide me with an example of the SOAP XML it would be great as almost all of the other available operations are the same so I cold see how to do it myself.

Thanks in advance

========

## EDIT

I have set up the WSDL reference in a C# project with visual studio to se what kind of request it makes

the config file it comes up with its the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
      <configuration>
         <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                  <customBinding>
            <binding name="Rest">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Rest" contract="SCJN.Tematica"
            name="Rest" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

But it doesent includes the address for the endpoint, so I modified the endpoint to look like this:

```
  <endpoint address="http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="Rest" contract="SCJN.Tematica"
        name="Rest" />
```

But the service responds with a endpoint not found.

So is there a way to find out wich address to call.
Also the WSDL does not list SOAPAction attributes but rather wsaw:Action in the operations supported, wich is translated in my .NET code to the following

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="urn:Tematica/ListaMinistros", ReplyAction="urn:Tematica/ListaMinistrosResponse")]

    ConsoleApplication2.SCJN.Ministro[] ListaMinistros(string actualizacion);
```

Comment: You don't need to understand the WSDL files! Just use "Add Service Reference". See [How to consume a web service](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/) if that's not a big enough hint.

Comment: The problem is that the client is not in .net but an app for iOS devices so I can´t use that option.

Comment: I'm surprised there is no such equivalent for iOS. Are you sure there's nothing like "wsdl2java"?

Comment: Thanks for your response, theres one wsdl2objc so I shall try it.

Answer (score 1):

Try soapUI.org, it's a feature rich opensource/commercial web service explorer. You can feed in the WSDL and it will automatically create SOAP request stubs, which can be send to the endpoints named in the WSDL. Even the HTTP headers can be made visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can download webservice studio.
Its free program and it will show you a soap message. Search in the google.

Comment: I can invoke methods from the webservice studio for other services, but for some reason I cant invoke methods using http://iberius.scjn.gob.mx:8080/Mobile/Tematica.svc?wsdl, it downloads the file OK but in the invoke tab appears empty

Comment: Maybe the service does not expose wsdl ?

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

These articles [1][2] describes wsdl and soap.

The better options is to use the wsdl2java tool available with the platform. If there is no such thing available then you can use some other framework like Axis2 and examine the request and response messages for each and every operation.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/2873

[2] http://wso2.org/library/2935