# How can I view XML from a SOAP client that sends as request to web service?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, soap, client

How can I view the XML received from a soap client that sends a request to a web service?

I tried to view it using fiddler but I was not able to view the XML.

What tool should I be using?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net

Comment: That's not a duplicate unless he's stuck using ASMX services.

Comment: What is your service that you're interacting with?  WCF, asmx? Different service platforms have different debugging mechanisms

Comment: FYI, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net has several good solutions.  The responses do NOT all pertain only to ASP.Net or only to ASMX services.