# Processing a web request in ASP.NET without serving a web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Following is my problem scenario.

I have an ip address 1.2.3.4

My client will make a webrequest like : http://1.2.3.4/aaa&bbb&ccc

I need to capture this request and instead of serving a web page I want to do something with the "aaa&bbb&ccc" part.

This process will keep looping.

I know how to host a website or a web service on IIS. My confusion is, how do I receive the request on my IP and instead of serving a webpage, just eat it up and 'digest' it. I will have IIS 7 as the web server and ASP.Net/C# as my dev environment.

How do I do this? (Would using a RESTFull ASP web service be a good practice?)

Sincere thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are looking for **Web Service**, which grab a request from client(can be in static IP & method name), and do what ever developer wants with the entrance parameters(*without have to serve a page*).
you can read this for more informations [Getting raw soap data from a web reference client running in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300674/getting-raw-soap-data-from-a-web-reference-client-running-in-asp-net)

Comment: By the way, you don't need to do this with restfull api, soap api will be fine enught